# Selected folders under versioning Cornerstone

Tags: svn, symfony, cornerstone

I have a symfony project with the followin structure

```
SDCU
  |-app
  |-----cache
  |-----logs
  |-bin
  |-vendor
  |-src
  |-web
```

I want to import this project into SVN (1.7) but without including the cache, logs and vendor folders.

I know how to ignore a folder on a working copy but my doubt is how to import the project ignoring those folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [*How to Create and store a Symfony2 Project in Subversion*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_svn.html) cookbook entry.

Comment: How...did I... forgot this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't import, svn co + copy in WC + add svn:ignore + svn ci